# Product of terms in Arithmetic Progression modulo $r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

Let $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$ be the $n$<sup>th</sup> term of an Arithmetic Progression.

The product of the first $n$ terms is given by the formula,

$$a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_n = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a_1 + kd) = d^n {\Gamma \big({a_1 \over d} + n \big) \over \Gamma \big({a_1 \over d}\big) }$$

The question is about computing this product modulo an integer $r$.

I know we can iteratively compute the product residues using the direct multiplication of the AP terms using a computer. Is there an alternative direct method? The reason I ask is I have very long sequences and need only the residue modulo $r \in M$, where $M$ is a set of coprime modulii.

Answer (score 3):

Would you be happy with the assumption $\gcd(d,r)=1$? If so, then notice that $a_1,\dotsc,a_r$ is a complete residue system modulo $r$; consequently, one of the factors in $a_1\dotsb a_r$ is divisible by $r$, and so is the whole product you are interested in.

If $\gcd(d,r)=1$ is not assumed, then observing that all sub-products $P_k:=\prod_{i=(k-1)r+1}^{kr} a_i$ are equal to each other, your product can be computed in something like $O(\log(n/r)+r)$ operations. (Here $\log(n/r)$ is the number of operations to compute the $(n/r)$-th power of $P_1$.)

Comment: Let the arithmetic sequence be defined by $1 + 8n$.

So, we have the first $12$ terms: 

$$1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89$$

Let $r = 7, GCD(d,r) = GCD(8,7)  = 1$ and $r$ is prime.

$$s = n \mod r = 12 \mod 7 = 5$$

$$n+1-s = 12 + 1 - 5 = 8$$

$$P \equiv \pm a_8 a_9 \dots a_{12} \equiv \pm 57 \times 65 \times 73 \times 81 \times 89 \equiv \pm 1 \mod 7$$

But $\prod_{i=1}^{i=12} (1 + 8n) \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are right, there is a small details I have missed; I will correct my solution in a moment.

Comment: @Wtp: I initially thought the $GCD(d,r) = 1$ condition is not an issue for the problem I am working on based on your previous response. But with your edit, it seems $GCD(d,r) \ne 1$ is a more favorable choice for my problem. Having said that, $r | a_1 a_2 \dots a_n, \forall r $ such that $GCD(r,d) = 1$ sounds like a surprisingly broad statement.  Surely, if $r > a_n$, this can't be true.

Comment: Also, I found this paper: R. Tijdeman. On the product of the terms of a finite arithmetic progression, http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0708-06.pdf

This has some bounds on the largest prime factor of the product of terms in an AP.

Comment: The way you stated your question, I assumed that $r$ is relatively small as compared to $n$. On the other hand, $r\mid a_1\dotsb a_n$ is certainly possible even for $r>a_n$.

Comment: In the sequence $1, 9, 17, \dots, 89$, if I choose $r = 97$, a prime greater than 89 or $r = 83$, a prime less than 89, $r$ does not divide any term. So, how is the statement '... one of the factors in $a_1 \dots a_r$ is divisible by $r$, and so is the whole product you are interested in' true for general $r$? Are you saying this is true for certain $r$ relative to $n$?

Comment: The sequence $1,9,17,\dotsc,89$ has only twelve  terms; my claim (for this sequence) is that the product $1\cdot 9\cdot17\dotsb 89$ is divisible by $r$ for any $r\le 12$ with $\gcd(r,8)=1$.